# Groupby with mask and transform

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
POLY_KEY_I      Class     SP_Percent             
FS01080100SM001 NA               5.0
                MTGP            67.5
                Meadow          25.0
                Woodland         2.5
FS01080100SM002 PHP             85.0
                SP              15.0
```

and for each uniqe `POLY_KEY_I` if `Class` == `Meadow` and `SP_Percent` >= `20` I want to transform `MTGP` into `WMTGP`.

My desired output is this:

```
POLY_KEY_I      Class     SP_Percent             
FS01080100SM001 NA               5.0
                WMTGP           67.5
                Meadow          25.0
                Woodland         2.5
FS01080100SM002 PHP             85.0
                SP              15.0
```

The code I am trying is this:

```
df ['mask'] = ((df['Class'] == 'Meadow') & df['SP_Percent'] >=20)
mask = df.groupby(['POLY_KEY_I'])['mask'].transform('MTGP')
df.loc[mask,'Class']='WMTGP'
print(df)
```

but this returns the error:

> mask = final.groupby(['POLY_KEY_I'])['mask'].transform('MTGP')
>
> File "C:\Users\Stefano\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2439, in transform
>           return self._transform_fast(lambda : getattr(self, func)(*args, **kwargs))
>
> File "C:\Users\Stefano\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2484, in _transform_fast
>           values = func().values
>
> File "C:\Users\Stefano\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2439, in 
>           return self._transform_fast(lambda : getattr(self, func)(*args, **kwargs))
>
> File "C:\Users\Stefano\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 520, in **getattr**
>           (type(self).**name**, attr))
>
> AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'MTGP

EDIT:

I dont know if this helps but if I change this line:

`mask = df.groupby(['POLY_KEY_I'])['mask'].transform('MTGP')`

to this:

`mask = df.groupby(['POLY_KEY_I'])['mask'].transform('any')`

it will change every value for the respective `POLY_KEY_ID` to `WMTGP`, but I only want it changed if it is `MTGP`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completely change your solution to `groupby` with `apply` custom function `f`. For check string values is better use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html).

Input (added row 5 for testing):

```
        POLY_KEY_I     Class  SP_Percent
0  FS01080100SM001       NaN         5.0
1  FS01080100SM001      MTGP        67.5
2  FS01080100SM001    Meadow        25.0
3  FS01080100SM001  Woodland         2.5
4  FS01080100SM002       PHP        85.0
5  FS01080100SM002      MTGP        85.0
6  FS01080100SM002        SP        15.0
```

```
def f(g):
    if ((g['Class'].isin(['Meadow'])) & (g['SP_Percent'] >=20)).any():
       g['Class'].loc[g['Class'].isin(['MTGP'])] = 'WMTGP'
       return g
    else:
       return g

print df.groupby(['POLY_KEY_I']).apply(f)
        POLY_KEY_I     Class  SP_Percent
0  FS01080100SM001       NaN         5.0
1  FS01080100SM001     WMTGP        67.5
2  FS01080100SM001    Meadow        25.0
3  FS01080100SM001  Woodland         2.5
4  FS01080100SM002       PHP        85.0
5  FS01080100SM002      MTGP        85.0
6  FS01080100SM002        SP        15.0
```

EDIT1:

Added timing:

```
%timeit df.groupby(['POLY_KEY_I']).apply(f)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.78 ms per loop

%timeit shahram(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 38.2 ms per loop
```

Source for timing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

temp=u"""POLY_KEY_I;Class;SP_Percent
FS01080100SM001;NA;5.0
FS01080100SM001;MTGP;67.5
FS01080100SM001;Meadow;25.0
FS01080100SM001;Woodland;2.5
FS01080100SM002;PHP;85.0
FS01080100SM002;MTGP;85.0
FS01080100SM002;SP;15.0"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", index_col=None, parse_dates=False)
print df
print df.dtypes
print df.index

def shahram(df):
    df ['mask'] = ((df['Class'] == 'Meadow') & (df['SP_Percent'] >=20))
    df2 = df[(df['mask']==True)][['POLY_KEY_I']]
    df2['mask2']=True
    df = pd.merge(df,df2,how='left')
    df.ix[((df['mask2']==True) & (df['Class']=='MTGP')),'Class'] = 'WMTGP'
    return df

def f(g):
    if ((g['Class'].isin(['Meadow'])) & (g['SP_Percent'] >=20)).any():
       g['Class'].loc[g['Class'].isin(['MTGP'])] = 'WMTGP'
       return g
    else:
       return g

print df.groupby(['POLY_KEY_I']).apply(f)
print shahram(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it:

```
df ['mask'] = ((df['Class'] == 'Meadow') & (df['SP_Percent'] >=20))
df2 = df[(df['mask']==True)][['POLY_KEY_I']]
df2['mask2']=True
df = pd.merge(df,df2,how='left')
df.ix[((df['mask2']==True) & (df['Class']=='MTGP')),'Class'] = 'WMTGP'
```